# Using same Webdriver 2 times

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to reuse the same driver 2 times in the same program. 
I want to do this so I can run the same test on multiple browsers.

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
test();
closeDriver();

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/eclipse/chrome/chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
test();
closeDriver();
```

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: no such session
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 113 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.43.0', revision: '597b76b', time: '2014-09-09 20:52:38'
>   System info: host: 'HPATE-E5420', ip: '10.16.70.161', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
>   Session ID: d38ea9501aa738784e2aa3f7ad9edced
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\hpate\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6692_16996}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=37.0.2062.120, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:162)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:304)
>       at jUnitTestCases.VerifyRole.test(VerifyRole.java:66)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Comment: It depends on what `closeDriver()` is doing.  If you're using `driver.Close()`, then what you're attempting should be possible.  Could you be more specific on how this is not working?

Comment: Yea i tried both driver.close() and .quit() but both are giving me exceptions. .close() gives me org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: no such session

Comment: Could you edit your post and add in the exception?  It might also be helpful to see more of how your code is structured.

Comment: im not sure how to use this so much but i just copied and pasted it in

Comment: It was very useful.  I can see you're running Selenium WebDriver 2.43, Chrome 37, and ChromeDriver 2.9.  I would suggest updating to ChromeDriver 2.10, and trying again:  http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.10/

Comment: Show us what `closeDriver()` and `test()` is actually doing. What line is actually failing here?

Comment: close method---
 public void closeDriver(){
  driver.close();
 }

Comment: figured out why i was doing that. I took                      `test();
closeDriver();` away from after i created the chromedriver and everything runs smoothly now

Comment: Unsure how you expect us to solve it, when you didn't show the code that you are using.